# RecyclerView update last position with continuous data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, google-cloud-speech

first of all when i'll get to my computer i will post code.

I'm trying to add and update the RecyclerViews from Speechrecognition data.
For SpeechRecognition i'm using Google Cloud Speech 
I'm making a "Chat - view" every time the Speech is completed is adding the result to RecyclerView. I want to modify it by adding the new item as the onVoice() is recognized and update it as is recognizing the speech ( the result is still not final)

My approach was: as the SpeechRecognition is triggered by voice the new item is added (onVoiceStart) as the recognizers onVoice callback is triggered (new speech data chunk is recognized) i will delete the RecyclerViews last item and add the "chunk" to last position and after that calling adapter.notifyItemChanged(speechResults.size()-1)

Comment: paste you full activity and adapter code

Comment: The first line of the post. Thank you for your down vote

Comment: I have not cast downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I :

```
     // Step 1: find the holder 
 RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(speechResults.size() - 1);

     //   Step 2: Check if the holder is not null and if has itemView .
    if (holder != null) {

        if (holder.itemView != null) {
            // from itemview find the TextView  and set the desired text :
            if (holder.getAdapterPosition() == speechResults.size() - 1) {
                ((TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.speech_sent_textView))
                        .setText(text);
            }
        }
 // Now update the adapter item also but do not notify the adapter change.
```

Solution II  : Using library  [LastAdapter](https://github.com/nitrico/LastAdapter)

1. Add Dependecy -> follow [this](https://github.com/nitrico/LastAdapter)
2. in the Layout add new the root tag **"< layout"**

   ```
               //Delte the space after "<"
     < layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <data>
       <variable name="item" type="com.github.nitrico.lastadapterproject.item.Header"/>
   </data>

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       // you use  like thius "@{youritem.speecSent"
       android:text="@{item.text}"/>
       //Delte the space after "< "
    < /layout>
   ```

   NOTE: for using multiple layouts the data tag must have same variable name.

   ```
      <data>   
          // this name has to be same in every xml layout types.
       <variable name="item" type="com.github.nitrico.lastadapterproject.item.Header"/>
       </data>
   ```
3. Java part: 
   NOTE : **listOfItems must be Observable ArrayList**

   ```
     speechResults = new ObservableArrayList<>();
        ...
       new LastAdapter(speechResults , BR.item)
      .map(SpeechResult.class, R.layout.speech_sent)
      .map(SpeechResult.class, R.layout.speech_received)
      .into(recyclerView);
   ```

BR.item   - > you have to enable the databinding in build Gradle.
the .item - > is the name given in the layout for data (that has to be same)

if you want to handle the LayoutType using the same Item type (Class)

```
            new LastAdapter(speechResults, BR.item )
            .map(SpeechResult.class, R.layout.speech_sent_content)
            .map(SpeechResult.class, R.layout.speech_received_content)
              .handler(new TypeHandler() {
                  @Nullable
                  @Override
                  public BaseType getItemType(Object o, int i) {
                      if(((SpeechResult) o).getSpeechType()==SpeechResult.SPEECH_TYPE_SENT){
                          return new BaseType(R.layout.speech_sent_content);
                      }
                      return new BaseType(R.layout.speech_received_content);
                  }
              })

            .into(recyclerView);
```

to adding new items in the recyclerView 
 simply add item to your itemlist. LastAdapter will handle the refresh of data.